# Invalid Conversion from char* to int . C++ Error;

Tags: c++, do-while

I'm confused here. Why am I getting this error?

```
Running /home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:22:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
              case "-" : 
                   ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:22:19: error: ‘(int)((long int)"-")’ is not a constant expression
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:31:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
              case "*" : 
                   ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:31:19: error: ‘(int)((long int)"*")’ is not a constant expression
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:40:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
              case "/" : 
                   ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:40:19: error: ‘(int)((long int)"/")’ is not a constant expression
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:14: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const char [41]’)
         cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
              ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:14: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from /home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.tcc:996:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.tcc:996:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:17: note:   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>’
         cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:882:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40,
                 from /home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/istream.tcc:955:5: note: template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/istream.tcc:955:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:17: note:   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>’
         cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:882:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40,
                 from /home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/istream.tcc:923:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT& __c)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/istream.tcc:923:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:17: note:   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>’
         cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:727:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char& __c)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:727:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:17: note:   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>’
         cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:732:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char& __c)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:732:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:17: note:   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>’
         cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:774:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:774:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:17: note:   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>’
         cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:779:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:779:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:17: note:   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>’
         cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:872:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, _Tp&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __is, _Tp& __x)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:872:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.cpp:50:17: note:   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>’
         cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
                 ^
```

For this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char option,continueCheck;
        int a,b,res;
    cout << "********** Welcome to the operation game ********* " <<endl;
    do{
        cout << "Please type (+,-,/,*) to add your numbers " <<endl;
        cin >> option;
        switch(option){
            case '+' : 
               cout << "Please type in the first number" <<endl;
               cin >> a;
               cout << "Please type in the second number" <<endl;
               cin >> b;
               res = a+b;
               printf("%d + %d = %d \n" , a,b,res);
               break;

             case "-" : 
               cout << "Please type in the first number" <<endl;
               cin >> a;
               cout << "Please type in the second number" <<endl;
               cin >> b;
               res = a-b;
               printf("%d + %d = %d \n" , a,b,res);
               break;

             case "*" : 
               cout << "Please type in the first number" <<endl;
               cin >> a;
               cout << "Please type in the second number" <<endl;
               cin >> b;
               res = a*b;
               printf("%d + %d = %d \n" , a,b,res);
               break;

             case "/" : 
               cout << "Please type in the first number" <<endl;
               cin >> a;
               cout << "Please type in the second number" <<endl;
               cin >> b;
               res = a/b;
               printf("%d + %d = %d \n" , a,b,res);
               break;   
        }

        cout >> "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
        cin >> continueCheck;

    }while(continueCheck = 'y');
}
```

I mean I'm obviously not converting `char` to `int` anywhere. I didn't even learn how to do that. Like I'm confused here. Did it think `'+'` was an `int` or something?

Comment: `case "-"` → `case '-'`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Biffen !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your cases you're using double quotes, which correspond to `const char*`. You want to use single quotes, which are `char`s.

The reason it's complaining about conversion from `const char*` to `int` is that `char` is promoted to an `int` type.

There are a number of other problems with your program, though.

- All of your `printf`s print the same thing (which is incorrect 75% of the time).
- You need to use an double equals to check equality in your `while`.
- You're using an extraction operator `>>` at the end for `std::cout` - should be `<<`.

Here's a (more) correct version:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char option,continueCheck;
        int a,b,res;
    cout << "********** Welcome to the operation game ********* " <<endl;
    do{
        cout << "Please type (+,-,/,*) to add your numbers " <<endl;
        cin >> option;
        switch(option){
            case '+' : 
               cout << "Please type in the first number" <<endl;
               cin >> a;
               cout << "Please type in the second number" <<endl;
               cin >> b;
               res = a+b;
               printf("%d + %d = %d \n" , a,b,res);
               break;

             case '-' : 
               cout << "Please type in the first number" <<endl;
               cin >> a;
               cout << "Please type in the second number" <<endl;
               cin >> b;
               res = a-b;
               printf("%d - %d = %d \n" , a,b,res);
               break;

             case '*' : 
               cout << "Please type in the first number" <<endl;
               cin >> a;
               cout << "Please type in the second number" <<endl;
               cin >> b;
               res = a*b;
               printf("%d * %d = %d \n" , a,b,res);
               break;

             case '/' : 
               cout << "Please type in the first number" <<endl;
               cin >> a;
               cout << "Please type in the second number" <<endl;
               cin >> b;
               res = a/b;
               printf("%d / %d = %d \n" , a,b,res);
               break;   
        }

        cout << "Want to continue? Enter Y or y OR N or n" << endl;
        cin >> continueCheck;

    }while(continueCheck == 'y');
}
```

See it in action [here](http://ideone.com/hqniBr).

Comment: `while(continueCheck = 'y');` is wrong too. Since OP wrote `'+'` but `"-"` etc I think OP just needs to pay closer attention to his/her code.

Comment: _"I mean I'm obviously not converting char to int anywhere."_ Yeah, OP is trying to, without realising. Because that's what `case` expects.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just posted a hasty answer. Was going to enumerate other problems in the program, but that's the immediate problem. :)

Comment: Not criticising just chatting. Although FGITW=bad now you mention it :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit For sake of completeness I've added all logical problems I could find. Didn't address style or best practices. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a substatial difference between `'-'` and `"-"`:

- The former is a single integer of type `char` and value 45 (ASCII value of -)
- The latter is a character *string*. The contents of the string is a 2-element array {45,0}, where 45 is the ASCII code for `-` and 0 marks the end of the string. The value of the string as a whole is a pointer to the memory where it is stored.

Effectively, what your code tries to do, is to compare the value of `option` to the pointer to the memory. The fix is to change the quotes.

There are other errors in your code, most prominently the

```
while(continueCheck = 'y')
```

it *assigns* the value `'y'` to the `continueCheck` and continues the loop if the value assigned is nonzero (which is always true). You most likely wanted to *compare* `continueCheck` with `y` which is done through the operator `==`, and not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

May be a typing error!?
Line 22: the compiler needs an integer at this position, but this is a string, a pointer.
Line 13: type it like here: '-'

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: The Question was: "Why am I getting this error?"

Comment: Answers should be definite, not _probably_.